# SFTP and cURL - connection parameters in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, curl

We are utilizing a third party API to perform batch processing of data. We provide an input file, the API fetches, reads its, does the processing and uploads the final file to a location we specify.

Our server only accepts SFTP connections, with private / public keys. The API uses parameters in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to identify input and output locations.

If the connection parameters weren't being passed in the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS section, we could use CURLOPT_SSLKEY to share the key location.

Any ideas on how to proceed? Also, is it safe to provide a key in this manner?

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.processing.com",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
    'input' => [
        'file' => 'https://example.com/input.csv'
    ],
    'output' => [
        'file' => 'sftp://example.com:port/output.csv',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password' // This can be provided, but server does not accept password, only keys
                  
    ]
  ]),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "authorization: API_KEY_123"
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: _"Any ideas on how to proceed?"_ - depends on your API ...? We don't _know_ if that provides _any_ options to specify `output` in the way you want.

Comment: Right. I was assuming this was a very standard approach. Doesn't sound like it is and is API dependant.

Comment: _"we could use CURLOPT_SSLKEY to share the key location"_ - no, you could not, that would only affect your connection that cURL makes to the API server. But that one is not your problem to begin with here. The API server itself needs to make a connection to your system, apparently, to store the resulting file. And for configuring _that_ connection, you are limited to what parameters the API takes. If it does not offer an option to configure its `output` parameter to fulfill your requirements, then you will need to look for some other solution.